# Is the Ralph Williams angry car salesman clip real?

Tags: united-states, video, television

Someone sent me [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUsW1CDJdxc) of a car salesman supposedly working for Ralph Williams, a dealership owner in the Bay Shore area. There are lots of references online to this video. See the google results for a search on "[ralph williams bay shore](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ralph+williams+bay+shore#q=ralph+williams+bay+shore&hl=en&prmd=ivnso&ei=3W8sTq7lHo7-sQKzg9WdCw&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=6738bf4e4a8a45f4&biw=1252&bih=603)" for example.

The quote going along with this clip is as follows (it was in the email containing the video sent to me, and I found it verbatim [elsewhere](http://olddogg.com/offbeat/live-commercial-from-the-60s-car-salesman-unhappy-with-his-boss-nsfw-language/)):

> During the late 60's, most television programs and commercials were live. There were no "pre-recorded" programs. There were some obvious problems with this method. No "retakes" and "bloopers" were a regular occurrence.
>
> This is no blooper! This guy was just VERY upset with his boss, and told it like he thought it was. What a great job of ad-libbing. He never misses a beat while the camera man is just about to lose it.
>
> The commercial got on the air... but only once.
>
> We have to assume he quit right after the commercial -- one way or another.

I have an extremely hard time imagining that this ever aired. Can anyone confirm or deny the following:

- This commercial actually aired on TV
- During the late 60's, most television programs and commercials were live

Comment: Along with this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK6BksCzTKs&NR=1

Comment: If you google, Ralph Williams you also see a similar commecial for a dealership in Seattle by the same name but not quite as funny. Same actor. Definately fake because he could not have made two of them in two cities unless it was a big publicity stunt, high risk high reward. Doubtful in the late 60's. This certainly was out takes or a roast to the owner that they actually liked.

Comment: Having spent 40 years in the advertising/marketing business this ad is what Used to be called the "corporate version". It was tongue in cheek, always funny and called the corporate version because it was something that would never be sent to the corporate headquarters. At least that's what I think this is.

Comment: Chick Lambert and his dog Storm were for real in the early 1960's in Southern CA. He sponsored movies with few comm'l interruptions and was well respected. He went to work for Ralph Williams in the late 60's=early 70's. Williams is infamous for taking Ford Motor Company for tens of millions of dollars in a staged corporate bankruptcy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hmmm. my gut says this is an outtake of some sort done for fun.

Indeed several of the links I found whilst searching for this clip referred to it as an outtake.

There are several things that strike me as "odd" in this story.

First - I think the statement "During the late 60's, most television programs and commercials were live" is probably demonstrably untrue (especially for TV).

Here's a couple of anecdotal sounding links listing the sort of TV watched in the 60's, mostly pre-recorded.

- [List of 60's television shows.](http://the60sofficialsite.com/Television_in_the_60s.html)
- [Here's a UK style list](http://www.downthelane.net/growing-up-50s-60s/tv-1960s.php)

Second - As I said, several clips I found were referred to as out-takes. Indeed [this link](http://hogwhitman.com/2010/12/31/cracking-under-the-strain/) describes it as a

> Here’s a very NSFW, **never broadcast** outtake from one of those early
>   spots.

The chap doing the talking is apparently Chick Lambert, there's a [Snopes thread](http://message.snopes.com/showthread.php?t=60045) on this which is pretty much inconclusive, but comes up with similar points to me.

Other (mildly) circumstantial evidence for this being never broadcast is that there are several links referring to the advertising rivalry between Chick Lambert, and Cal Worthington, but not one mentions Chick Lambert turning on his boss.

1. [Heres  a NY Times Article](http://articles.latimes.com/2008/dec/21/local/me-then21)
2. [A bit of oral/anecdotal history](http://michaelconnelly.websitetoolbox.com/post?id=4895139)

I don't think there's a "smoking gun" saying this was definitely fake, or if there is I couldn't find it, but I find it hard to believe this wouldn't be referred to in articles looking back at the times if it were true. Especially when referencing the competing ad campaigns etc.